# Opengl, simple animation

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to make simple animation in Opengl. My agenda is to move object in one direction. I'm doing this by using glm:translate:

```
int iModelViewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "modelViewMatrix");

mModelView = glm::translate(mModelView,
    glm::vec3(dxb1, 0.0, -12.41989));

glUniformMatrix4fv(iModelViewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mModelView));
brama1->Draw();
```

And my function to animate this is by function which are activated by pressing key and:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 116; i++)
    {
        dxb1 = dxb1 + 0.05;
    }
```

But I dont see animation, just first point of move and the last one. How can I change this to see animation?

Comment: Because that loop does not draw anything. The variable gets updated, but unless your (unnamed!) programming language is highly imperative, its only effect is to set `dxbl` immediately to the end value.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create an animation loop, and on every frame update the value. Even better, if on every frame, you calculate the desired position based on time. if you use glut:

```
int oldTimeSinceStart = 0;

while( ... )
{
     int timeSinceStart = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
     int deltaTime = timeSinceStart - oldTimeSinceStart;
     oldTimeSinceStart = timeSinceStart;

     //your part
     dxb1 = dxb1 + deltaTime * 0.05;
}
```

Comment: What library I need to import to do that?

Comment: it really seems like you're new on opengl, so go with glut.